# Represent a 2D point using siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I want to represent a 2D point in a space with SI units, something like `(2,1mm; 2mm)` or `(2,1; 2)mm`, whatever is considered best in the world of typography.

Is there a proper way to do this with with `siunitx`? Or do I just do

```
(\SI{2}{mm}; \SI{2}{mm})
```

The point of the question is that I don't know how to best represent a 2D point with units in text, so a predefined command with sane defaults would be useful.

Edit: I'm looking for an answear which adapts easily to different countries, without breaking consisntency.

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways of writing them. The first one is more flexible, in that it sets a default output of millimetres, which could be changed by an optional parameter. The second one, is more simple, but it is also the only way I have ever seen it written in textbooks.

As for the confusing writing in countries where the decimal marker is a comma, in most books I have seen, they write the 2D and and 3D-points in the same way as they do in the rest of the world, changing the decimal marker to a dot. I don't know if that is true for all countries, but that is the practice in Norway. I have added code for this, using `\sisetup`.

It now uses `\SIlist` and `\numlist` as requested in comment. The `\sisetup{}`-command should possible be put inside the `\NewDocumentCommand`, with braces around the content, so that it only effect the command, and not a global change.

Of course, there is also the possibility of simply writing it out fully. For instance, something like:

*A fence is 3 meters long and 5 meters wide.*

It all depends on what it is exactly you are writing.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\sisetup{list-pair-separator= {; }}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Point}{mmo}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}%
    {%
    \mbox{(\numlist{#1;#2})}%% mboxes are here just to stop linebreak within a point.
    }{%
    \mbox{(\SIlist{#1;#2}{#3})}%
    }%
    }
\begin{document}

We have a point at \Point{2.2}{3} and another point at \Point{5}{6.66}[\centi\metre].
Alternatively, one could write:
A fence is \SI{3.3}{\metre} long and \SI{5,7}{\metre} wide.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was looking for a more international answear. If one uses floating point numbers it can get ugly. Think \Point{2.1}{2.1} in a country (like my own) where decimal separators are ',' -> (2,1mm, 2,1mm).
Also that's essentially my code wrapped in a command. But +1 for using \NewDocumentCommand for readability (didn't know it).

Comment: I used `newDocumentCommand` becouse it is easier to set up optional commands in it. It requires `xparse`, but most new packages use it anyway, I believe. I made an edit to the answer.

Comment: Hehe, that's cheating! By forcing the comma into a dot, you bring inconsistency to the document. But point taken, now the end-user does as he pleases with that.
I'll wait a couple of days to see if someone comes up with a better answear, then mark this as solved. I don't what I want exists in the form I want :P

Comment: Well, It's one way of doing it. You can have a look at [How do Europeans write a list of numbers with decimals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104071/how-do-europeans-write-a-list-of-numbers-with-decimals). You can change these settings to whatever fits your reader.

Comment: Because your link mentioned "list", I thought of SIlist:
`(\SIlist[list-pair-separator={, }, list-units=repeat]{2.1;2}{mm})`
is closer to what I want, but `list-pair-separator` should have whatever the value of `list-separator` is, in this case. If you know how to do it, put in your answear and I'll accept it now :)
Even if you don't, since your comment gave me the idea, update it, and I'll mark it.
I prefer SIlist because it's more general, for other dimensions, and also has the options of (1mm, 1mm) or (1, 1)mm, etc, without having to write complex or many newcommands.

Comment: Let me know if there is anything missing now